# Why my parseInt function is not converting my string into integer?

Tags: javascript, string, integer, addition, parseint

What am I going wrong here? I'm trying to convert a string to an integer to use in addition.

I have an image with a class of `portfolio` and a src of `images/portfolio-images/gbn1.jpg`

The first alert says the value of `imageInt` is `1`, but the second alert says the value of `newImg` is `gbn11.jpg` when I'm trying to get `gbn2.jpg`.

I am posting my code below:

```
var mainImg = $('.active-more').closest(".container").find("img.portfolio:first").attr("src");
var nofilename = mainImg.replace("images/portfolio-images/",""); 
nofilename = nofilename.replace(".jpg",""); 
var imageString = nofilename.replace(/[A-Za-z$-]/g, "");
var imageInt = parseInt(imageString, 10);   
var imageProject = nofilename.replace(/\d+/g, '');  
alert(imageInt);
var newImg= imageProject + imageInt + 1 + ".jpg";
alert(newImg);
```

Comment: +1 for naming variables in sample to show type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing string concatenation due to order of `+` - add braces to fix:

```
 var newImg= imageProject + (imageInt + 1) + ".jpg";
```

Comment: @maskedj: try my answer below

Comment: @lwburk, not sure where do you see a problem: string + int or int + string produces string, but int + int produces int (Number to be precise). So when one forces `(imageInt + 1)` to be executed first it will be int+int, and than go to string+int/ int+string route.

Comment: @lwburk :) no problem, it is actually realatively surprising to see variable name to actually reflects what is stored there.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I work on legacy code that extensively uses Hungarian notation, so I actually see it a lot. No excuses here :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
var newImg= imageProject + (imageInt + 1) + ".jpg";
```

The + operator is used to add numbers and to concatenate strings. If the left operand is a string then the right one is converted to  a string.

In the above, by enclosing the `imageInt + 1` in parentheses we ensure that it is evaluated as an integer before being concatenated as a string.

See the fiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/VQG5j

Comment: @lwburk—you can delete comments if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You try the adding stuff separately and concatenate it to the image name, use `parseInt` on adding too.

Try the code construct given below:

```
var mainImg = $('.active-more').closest(".container").find("img.portfolio:first").attr("src");
var nofilename = mainImg.replace("images/portfolio-images/",""); 
nofilename = nofilename.replace(".jpg",""); 
var imageString = nofilename.replace(/[A-Za-z$-]/g, "");
var imageInt = parseInt(imageString, 10);   
var imageProject = nofilename.replace(/\d+/g, '');  
alert(imageInt);
imgIntNew = imageInt + parseInt(1);
alert(imageIntNew);
var newImg= imageProject + imgIntNew + ".jpg";
alert(newImg);
```